# Unable to insert into table using PDO in mysql

Tags: php

my table structure is

```
id int(10)auto increment primary key,
value varchar(10)
```

and sql command is

```
INSERT into table (id,value) Values('','amit');
```

Kindly suggest me the error in my query  thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your query

```
INSERT into table (value) values('amit');
```

Answer (score 2):

The `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute can be used to generate a unique identity for new rows

Primary key states that column mustn't have NULL values, No value was specified for the AUTO_INCREMENT column, so MySQL assigned sequence numbers automatically.

By default, the starting value for AUTO_INCREMENT is 1, and it will increment by 1 for each new record. You can remove `id` column and its value from your query